# Http interceptor response cache vs server

Tags: angularjs

In my angular app I have an http interceptor that will perform some operation fn(x) on every response from the server. The problem I have encountered is that the angular $http service will still hit the interceptor when it is returning a response from its own cache. So, because one of my $http calls is using cache = true in it's config, I end up executing fn(x) on calls that do not reach the server.
Is there any lower level way in angular to determine whether the response actually came from the server rather than from angular's cache?

Comment: Is this interceptor a request or response? Surely angular will set the status to something other than 200 if it was cached?

Comment: Nope, the response object in the interceptor has a status value of 200 and a status message of 'Ok'. I know it is being served from the cache because in dev tools only the first request shows in the network tab (xhr).